# After running bundle install I got this message "cannot load such file -- appium_lib"

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber, appium

I was running my codes without any issues while I was only automating my wep app.
Now I wanted to start automating my mobile app and after running bundle install I'm getting this error. I don't know where else I can find the solution for this error.

I guess is some gem that is not correct installed but already removed all gems and it didn't work.

```
cannot load such file -- appium_lib (LoadError)
/Users/brunobacelar/Curatio/Automation/ui_tests/iOS/features/support/env.rb:3:in `require'
/Users/brunobacelar/Curatio/Automation/ui_tests/iOS/features/support/env.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/brunobacelar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/cucumber-7.0.0/lib/cucumber/glue/registry_and_more.rb:121:in `require'
/Users/brunobacelar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/cucumber-7.0.0/lib/cucumber/glue/registry_and_more.rb:121:in `load_code_file'
/Users/brunobacelar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/cucumber-7.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:142:in `load_file'
/Users/brunobacelar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/cucumber-7.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:81:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/brunobacelar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/cucumber-7.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:80:in `each'
/Users/brunobacelar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/cucumber-7.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:80:in `load_files!'
/Users/brunobacelar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/cucumber-7.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:260:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/brunobacelar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/cucumber-7.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:72:in `run!'
/Users/brunobacelar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/cucumber-7.0.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:29:in `execute!'
/Users/brunobacelar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/cucumber-7.0.0/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/brunobacelar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/Users/brunobacelar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
/Users/brunobacelar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/Users/brunobacelar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
```

env.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'appium_lib' 
require 'rubygems' 
require 'pry'

# creating an array from the data in the YML file 
APPCONSTANT=YAML.load_file('/Users/brunobacelar/Curatio/Automation/ui_tests/iOS/config/appConstants.yml')

def caps   { caps: {
    platformVersion: "14.5",
    deviceName: "iPhone SE2",
    platformName: 'iOS',
    automationName: 'XCUITest',
    bundleId: "me.curatio.st-i",
    udid: "XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    newCommandTimeOut: '3600',
    xcodeOrgId: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    xcodeSigningId: 'iPhone Developer',
    noReset: true   } } end

# $driver = Appium::Driver.new(caps, true) Appium::Driver.new(caps, true) Appium.promote_appium_methods Object
```

Answer (score 0):

there you go. You've answered your own question. It cannot load `appium_lib` which you have specified on line3 of your env.rb.

Usually you would ensure this is inside your Gemfile or suchlike. Double check that your Gemfile.lock has the relevant gems, your ruby version is correct for where you're running and that you also are requiring the right path